# Using a component inside a select

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to use a custom component inside a `select` element, something like:

```
<select value.bind="selectValue" name="myname">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select option</option>

  <my-component></my-component>
</select>
```

And `my-component` is something like:

```
<template>
  <option value="something">Some text</option>
</template>
```

So I'm expecting this option to be included inside my select.

But seems like it's not working.

My question is: is it not possible to use a custom component inside a select as I'm using it?

Cheers!!

Comment: I could be wrong but I think  `<select>` can have only `<option>` or `<optgroup>`  as children. I don't know how `<template>` or custom elements behave within select.

Comment: @adiga seems to be correct. I played with this in a gistRun and couldn't get it to work even using compose.

Answer (score 1):

Since `<select>` only accepts `<option>` and `<optgroup>`, you cannot use a custom-element inside it. However, you can use `as-element` to avoid this error. Like this:

```
<select value.bind="selectValue" name="myname">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select option</option>

  <option as-element="my-component"></option>
</select>
```

But before using this approach, make sure that `my-component` really makes sense in this case. I would think twice before using a custom-element for rendering simple things, such as `<option>`. Perhaps a custom-attribute would be a better choice.